# How remove passwords in Django signup form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django CustomerUser model , and as most webapp today just ask for email for sigup and later on after email confirmation user can set the password wondering how can implement this workflow in django authentication.

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="email address",
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django import forms


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["email"]

     


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["email"]
```

[image]